How can i get App service environment settings from Azure in an excel file using powershell?
I want to be able to be able to get the environement settings of an app service in azure and display the values in an excel spreadsheet using powershell .
  So basically if one setting is let say serviceName and the 
 value is servicetest.com,another setting is connectionstring 
 and value is "Data Source=myServer;Initial 
 Catalog=myDB;Integrated  Security=true;Column Encryption 
  Setting=enabled;"  then in excel 

I want it to display as follows
B                     C   <---- excel columns
      serviceName         servicetest.com     
      connectionstring    Data Source=myServer;Initial ....
       etc etc 

and so on and so forth for all the retrieved values from tyhe environment settings.
How can i do this using Powershell ?
Having some trouble putting into excel but can get the app settings using  this ,
  az webapp config appsettings list --name <app_name> -- 
  resource-group <resource_group_name> --query "[].{Name:name, 
  Value:value}" --output table > appservice_env_variables.txt

Is that correct ?
How can i do this ?
Can i do a loop to get it for every app in the subscription ?

The simplest way is to use Export-CSV which can easily be read by excel. Writing to an xlsx file is much harder.

Use below PowerShell commands to fetch the application settings of App Service and export the data to an Excel file.

Install ImportExcel module:

Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -Force


Retrieve Environment variables of App Service:

1. $appService = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <rg_name>-EUS -Name <App-name>
2. $appSettings = $appService.SiteConfig.AppSettings                                                         


3: Export Retrieved data to Excel:
1. $data = @()
2. foreach ($setting in $appSettings) { $key = $setting.Name $value = $setting.Value $data += [PSCustomObject]@{ Key = $key Value = $value } }
3. $outputPath = "./OutputFile.xlsx"
4.$data | Export-Excel -Path $outputPath -WorksheetName "AppSettings" -AutoSize -TableName "Settings"


I am able to export the application settings of App Service using the above-mentioned commands:

Exported the settings to Excel in the below format:


Thanks for the reply , now if i do it for one app service and it has a property lets say , "servicename" , what if another app service doesnt have that property , i want to be abloe to put it in the excel and add the value "missing". Is that possible ?

It adds all the properties available in App Service application settings
